# Why are un-exported functions' names still listed in MinGW DLLs?

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I have a DLL with these functions:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) foo1()
{
    printf("1");
}

void foo2()
{
    printf("2");
}
```

When opening the DLL in Dependency Walker, only `foo1()` is shown as exported, which is expected. However, when I opened the DLL file in a hex-editor, I noticed the string `_Z4foo2v`, which looks like an export-name.

But since `foo2()` is not marked for export, why is this string `_Z4foo2v` present?

Comment: Have you build a library with debug info or not? Since if you built it with debug info it is symbols from normal symbols. Try to strip the shared library and see if there are those symbols.

Comment: It was a debug build, yes. I tried the release build and `foo2()` was indeed not listed there. Thanks, you can post that as an answer then.

Comment: Actually if you read `man nm` you will see the `--dynamic` option which switches what types of sections to show (dynamic-only or all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you build a library with debug info or not? Since if you built it with debug info it is symbols from normal symbols. Try to strip the shared library and see if there are those symbols.

Actually if you read man nm you will see the --dynamic option which switches what types of sections to show (dynamic-only or all)